# AngularJS calendar - navigation buttons events

Tags: angularjs, calendar

I use the AngularJS calendar in my application. My question now would be, if there is a possibility with AngularJS to get the click event of button "today" and the buttons previous and next? The reason is that I will have my own buttons to navigate through the calendar.

[AngularJS calendar](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to use this plug for your comfortability

https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-bootstrap-calendar/#?example=kitchen-sink

which by default have previous next and today button